# touchpad drivers not working properly in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: touchpad, asus, 19.04

Touchpad drivers in Ubuntu 19.04 are not working properly in ASUS ROG Strix GL503.

Constantly touchpad is getting disabled and again i need to restart the drivers or wait for some time then after touchpad is working fine.

This issue is happening very frequently.

Comment: I'm facing trouble in both the releases.

Comment: I would delete the references to 18.10 as the only on-topic questions allowed on 18.10 (*which reached EOL weeks ago*) are how to upgrade to 19.04.